# The test results are not constant. in jest, testing-library

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest, testing-library

The results keep changing when I do the yarn test.

this is error name
"Request failed with status code 400"

but i already Api's request function is already mocking

like this

```
import * as api from '@api/user';

jest.mock('@api/user');

(api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw { response: { data: { code: 'EX_INVALID_APIKEY_2015' } } };
});


(api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      status: 'success',
      user: {
        id: '99b1231230',
        country: 'KR',
        language: 'ko',
      },
    }));
```

The test made of this is passing. But tests often fail. I wonder what I should suspect.

```
export const fetchApiKeyUpdate = async ({
  exchange,
  apiKey,
  secretKey,
  passphrase,
  otpCode,
}: ApiKeyUpdateRequest): Promise<UserInfoUpdateResponse | ApiAuthResponse> => {
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    apiKeyUpdateUrl,
    { apiKey, secretKey, passphrase, otpCode },
    { headers: { exchange } },
  );
  return data;
};
```

The bottom is part of the code that I modified.

```
jest.mock('@api/user');

describe('API Register Success', () => {
  const mockResponse = {
    status: 'success',
    user: {
      id: '99bd10e123400',
      userName: 't123st07',
      receiveMarketingInfo: true,
    },
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    (api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResponse);
  });

  it('키인증 성공시 아이콘 변경', async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <ApiRegistrationBinanceTab
        isOpen
        handleOpenTab={jest.fn()}
      />,
    );

    userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/api key/i), 'apikey');
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Verify/i }));

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(container.querySelector('#certified-icon')).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});

describe('API Register Fail', () => {
  const mockResponse = { response: { data: { code: 'EX_INVALID_APIKEY_2015' } } };

  beforeEach(() => {
    (api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockRejectedValueOnce(mockResponse);
  });

  it('remove input value if error code EX_INVALID_APIKEY_2015 or API_MANAGEMENT_ALREADY_REGISTERED', async () => {
    render(
      <ApiRegistrationBinanceTab
        isOpen
        handleOpenTab={jest.fn()}
      />,
    );

    userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/api key/i), 'apikey');
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Verify/i }));

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/api key/i)).toHaveValue('');
    });
  });
});
```

```
FAIL src/components/articles/modal/custom/forgotPassword/ForgotPassword.spec.tsx
  ● 비밀번호 변경 스텝별로 진행

    Request failed with status code 400

      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
      at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:62:7)
      at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/create-event-accessor.js:32:32)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners ...
```

i apply beforeEach and change mockimplementationOnce > mockResolvedValueOnce, mockRejectedValueOnce

But the problem is that failure appears intermittently as the pages(test) change.

What I'm curious about the error message is... i did mocking A function(like fetchAuthMail.. fetchApiKeyUpdate) of in a request.

So I don't know why the error message is coming from axios even though I don't think I actually put a request in the test.

Comment: How did you use the `api.fetchApiKeyUpdate`?

Comment: userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/enter a password/i), 'password');
 userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Verify/i })); >>fetchapikeyupdate

Comment: await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/api key/i)).toHaveValue('');
    });

Comment: sometime test all pass with warning UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `mockImplementation` because the function returns a Promise.
Just use `mockResolvedValue` and `mockRejectedValue` to make it return a Promise.

Moreover, you should separate mocks with some `describe` (one for each use case) and add mocks into `beforeAll` / `beforeEach` functions.

Personnally, I just tested it, I kept your @api/user.ts (I just added `axios` import) and by using these files it worked (100% working, never failing) :

index.ts

```
import * as api from '@api/user';

export const main = async () => {
  const response = await api.fetchApiKeyUpdate({
    exchange: 'fake-exchange',
    apiKey: 'fake-apiKey',
    secretKey: 'fake-secretKey',
    passphrase: 'fake-passphrase',
    otpCode: 'fake-otpCode',
  });
  return response.user;
};
```

index.spec.ts

```
import { main } from './index';

import * as api from '@api/user';
jest.mock('@api/user');

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  post: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    console.error('axios should be mocked !'); // If some logs are shown, it means that one axios request was not mocked.
  }),
}));

describe('UT main tests', () => {
  describe('error', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      (api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockRejectedValue({ response: { data: { code: 'EX_INVALID_APIKEY_2015' } } });
    });

    it('should rejects but not throw', async () => {
      // Note that if you want to use .toThrow() method, you should set in mockRejectedValue an Error
      await expect(main()).rejects.toStrictEqual({ response: { data: { code: 'EX_INVALID_APIKEY_2015' } } });
    });
  });

  describe('error thrown', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      (api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockRejectedValue(Error('FAKE ERROR'));
    });

    it('should rejects and throw', async () => {
      // All working
      await expect(main()).rejects.toThrow(Error);
      await expect(main()).rejects.toThrowError('FAKE ERROR');
      await expect(main()).rejects.toThrowError(Error('FAKE ERROR'));
    });
  });


  describe('success', () => {
    const mockResponse = {
      status: 'success',
      user: {
        id: '99b1231230',
        country: 'KR',
        language: 'ko',
      },
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
      (api.fetchApiKeyUpdate as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(mockResponse);
    });

    it('should return user', async () => {
      const response = await main();
      expect(response).toStrictEqual(mockResponse.user);
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT : I added a mock of axios post directly, you should check if an error log appears on your console. If so, it means you forgot to mock some axios calls.

Comment: this structure look good so I applied it.

Comment: But the problem I had is still there.

Comment: I edited the post you can check

Comment: I was doing spyOn in another place, so the actual request was coming in one place. But the error kept coming up on a different page, so I couldn't find it.
Your answer helped me a lot in writing the test code. Thank you~